# How to set up a Facebook Chat API connection when authorizing as a Desktop App

Tags: facebook, session, xmpp, chat, facebook-chat

The problem I am facing is that after I authorize my app for current user using
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (client-side flow)
I can't setup a XMPP connection as I need to know session key to access it. When using server-based flow, the session properties are being sent as a part of access token. And I didn't find a way to get the session key for my oAuth based authentication client-side flow.
Please suggest how can I get it.

I'm doing all requests from javascript (Google Chrome extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is actually deprecating the session key. They have just recently (a couple days after you posted the question i believe) updated their authentication method to no longer require the session key. If for whatever reason you still need it you can get it by looking up the auth.promote_session method in the REST API, but that is deprecated and will be removed come October.

If you check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ you should find that the access token will get you what you need now.

Comment: Thank you. It's hard to follow the different API changes when working on a big project.

Comment: Get used to it. Facebook is pretty infamous for changing it's API's a lot, and breaking old code. Usually you can check up on here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/ to try and keep track of it. They just implemented a new policy where they give at least 90 days warning of an API change/deprecation, so hopefully that turns out well.